# sql query help needed in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table in this format with more rows:

```
res_id  quiz_id     sender_id   user_id     answer_id   answer       points
1   115         10      13      45      75      1
2   115         10      13      46      79      1
3   115         10      13      47      83      0
4   118         1       3       51      90      0
5   118         1       3       51      90      0
6   115         10      13      45      75      1
```

I want to get results in php this way: 
If sender_id=10 and quiz_id > 3 (means if 115 is there 3 times or more) look for points (if points has three corresponding values of 1) return 1 else 0

In above example above i should get back 1 as quiz_id 115 is used more than 3 times and points have at least 3 corresponding values of 1

For below table i should get 0

```
res_id  quiz_id     sender_id   user_id     answer_id   answer       points
1   115         10      13      45      75      1
2   115         10      13      46      79      1
3   115         10      13      47      83      0
```

Can any one help me with this query?

Comment: What did you tried? Can you post your code?

Comment: What is your DB. The particular SQL requires a grouping/sum constraint. This constraint can be express differently depending upon the type of DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like

```
SELECT quiz_id , SUM(points) AS summe FROM mytable
WHERE sender_id = 10
GROUP BY quiz_id
HAVING summe > 2
```

Comment: +1 I had the same idea, but the sql might not be valid in the db Gurnor is using.

Comment: @Haim - I have another question. Can this be made in a way that this query also checks if user_id is not same?

Comment: SELECT quiz_id , SUM(points) AS summe , count(distinct user_id) as usercount FROM mytable
WHERE sender_id = 10
GROUP BY quiz_id
HAVING summe > 2 and usercount > 1

Comment: @Haim - Sorry to keep bugging you. One last question. I tried but cant figure out. Here is what i have so far:                       SELECT quiz_id, count( DISTINCT user_id ) AS usercount
FROM `quiz_result`
WHERE points =0
AND sender_id =2
GROUP BY quiz_id
HAVING usercount >2                                                 I am trying to select quiz_id where points are 0 for at least 3 times for each unique user_id.

Comment: try something like SELECT quiz_id,  COUNT(res_id) AS counter
FROM quiz_result 
WHERE points =0 AND sender_id =2 
GROUP BY quiz_id ,  user_id
HAVING counter > 2

Comment: @Haim - It works but only one problem it shows the result 3 times. Like it shows result for same quiz_id for 3 different user_id. Is there a way to show only 1 result for one quiz_id?